# Support vector regression based GIS anaysis

Tags: regression, gis, svm, latitude-longitude, prediction

I'm new here and I really want some help. I have a dataset including geographical information (longitude, latitude.. ) and I want to ensure the prediction of some aspects using this dataset with Support Vector Regression, but I don't know how to perform this task. I have the following inquires,

- Is there a specific precessing I need to go through?
- Does SVR consider a geographic dataset as normal data set or are there some specificities in term of tools and treatment?
- Any recommended prediction analytics tools (including SVR) considering geographical data?

Comment: Please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and update your question with relevant code trials. "What tools do you suggest I use?" is not a complete programming question.

Comment: @PixelEinstein  you are right, such I'm stuck I could not order my ideas to ask a good question, indeed the scope of my question is as follows: I am in the state of the art of a research work on the prediction of geographical data, I use a geographic dataset and I want to make the prediction using SVR. So my question is : if for example I will use WEKA as machine learning software does it consider the geographical dataset as a simple row dataset or there is a specific processing to ensure?

Answer (score 0):

This given solution is for the situation that you want to extract the independent variable base on the dependent variable from a raster.
but if you have you all dependent and independent data with their corresponding location you simply use svm function in R and you then add a raster or vector (new) data to your predict function for prediction, or you also can use the estimated coefficient of dependent variable in raster calculator in GIS and multiply them to the corresponding independent variable and finally you will get your predicted raster.

Simply you can do the following for spatial data in R.

First of all, the support vector regression can be used for prediction of real value and you can use the library("e1071") in R in order to execute this algorithm.

you can import your dataset as CSV along with lat and long columns.

transform your data.fram to Spatial data.frame

```
#Read data
dat<-read.csv(choose.files())

#convert the data to SPDF. 
dat_sp=SpatialPoints(cbind(dat$x,dat$y))

#add your Geographical referense system
dat_crs=CRS("+proj=utm +zone=39 +datum=WGS84")

#Data Frams for SpatialPoint Data(Creating a SpatialPoints data frame for dat)
dat_spdf=SpatialPointsDataFrame(coords = dat_sp,data = dat, proj4string = dat_crs)
plot(dat_spdf, col='blue', cex=1, pch=16, axes=TRUE)

#Extract value 
dat_spdf$ref <- extract(raster , dat_spdf)
```

then you can extract your data on a raster data or whatever you have(your independent variable).

and finally, you can use the following cold in R.

```
SVM(dependent ~.,independent)
```

But you need to really have an intuition about what the SVR is and how to evaluate the result.

you also can show your result as a final raster map.

you can use toolbox package or you may use raster package.